# Append QStandardItem in two QStandardItemModel at the same time

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

First I want to thank you in advance for your answers. I insert one QStandardItem in one QStandardItemModel and then display this model in a Tree View (A). After this I append the same item (pointer) to a new QStandardItemModel wich is associated with another Tree View (B). It is only displayed one empty item instead one item with the same text in this second case. If I make a copy of the item, the result the expected. Why can I not append the same item in two different models?

In this case is not useful to use QSortFilterProxyModel because modelA and modelB have the same data but following a very different structure.

Thank you very much.

If it is not possible to do this, which solution you suggest me? I though maintaining a correspondence between table models by using hash tables, but I think there is a easier solution.

I copy one code example.

```
QStandardItem * item = generateExampleItem();
modelA->invisibleRootItem()->appendRow(item); // will be visible to the user
modelB->invisibleRootItem()->appendRow(item); // will be invisible to the user
ui.treeViewA->setModel(modelA);
ui.treeViewB->setModel(modelB);
ui.treeViewA->show();
ui.treeViewB->show();
```

Comment: QStandardItems are owned by their model, so sharing them is not supported. I'd just create two items, one for each model. Or create a custom proxy model. (But that's a complex thing and might not be worth the effort)

Comment: Thank you Frank. That was what I guessed. I implemented a function to copy the items (I subclass QStandardItem) with all its children. I guess I am going to maintain the coherence with a hash table itemInModelA = correlation(itemInModelB) or something similar. Modifications in one item must take place also in the other item. I will use the changeItem signal to update the another model. Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you have two models that contain the same data? Would it be possible to have the same model used by two views? That's the kind of thing that the Qt model/view separation is intended for.

Comment: Hi Taylor. The problem is that the structure is very different. I have a tree implemented with two columns (nodes can have children) and I display it with a QTreeView. But for the second view I need some children to disappear, some children go to a third new column (so I need to change all the rows from 2 elements to 3) ... so that they are very different views. To be honest I am not sure if with a QSortFilterProxyModel or a subclass I can change so deeply the QStandardItem tree structure. Thanks for your answer.